# Azure Liquid connector - Divided_by issue

Tags: azure-logic-apps, connector, dotliquid

Hi I am trying to divide two numbers using Liquid map in logic app, but it is not working.  Here is my simple mapping code:

```
{
    "unitWeight":"{{ 4 | Divided_by: 2 }}"
}
```

output:

```
{
    "unitWeight": "4"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

DotLiquid uses *DividedBy*

Example:

```
{{ 10 | DividedBy: 2}}
```